# Ajax hybrid of HTML and JSON formats

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I try to send datas in different div thanks to this ajax function but it does not work.

Thanks to this form the user will select an option in the list and the ajax function will returns some datas, thanks to an array, in the salarie and formation div, but when i select an option nothing happen..

**My php file :**

```
if(isset($_POST['idSalarie'])){ 
$displayForm = $bdd->prepare(
    'SELECT poste_nom, ups_type_contrat, serv_nom, serv_id_resp, user_credit_cpf, user_indice_salarial,
     FLOOR( DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , user_dateentree ) /365 ) AS dateEntree 
     FROM USER 
     INNER JOIN USER_POSTE_SERVICE 
        ON USER.user_id= USER_POSTE_SERVICE.ups_poste_id  
     INNER JOIN POSTE 
        ON USER_POSTE_SERVICE. ups_poste_id = POSTE.poste_id 
     INNER JOIN SERVICE 
        ON USER_POSTE_SERVICE.ups_id_serv = SERVICE.serv_id 
     WHERE user_id = :idSalarie 
        ORDER BY user_nom ASC');
$displayForm->bindParam(':idSalarie', $_POST['idSalarie']);
$displayForm->execute();
$resDisplayForm=$displayForm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data = array( 'resDisplayForm'=>'');
foreach ($resDisplayForm as $key => $value) {
    $data['resDisplayForm'][$key] .=  $value;
}

$data['salarie'] = '          
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="poste_nom" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Poste occupé</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="poste_nom" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>';

$data['formation'] = '
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="user_credit_cpf" class="col-sm-2 control-label" readonly>Crédits CPF</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_credit_cpf" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>';}

echo json_encode($data);die;
```

**My Ajax function :**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#idSalarie').change(function(){
    var req=$('#idSalarie').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "lib/function.php",
        data: "idSalarie="+req,
        dataType : "json",
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest + '--' + textStatus + '--' + errorThrown);
        },
        success:function(data){
            //On affiche la réponse du serveur
            $('.salarie').empty();
            $('.salarie').prepend(data.salarie);
            $('input[name=poste_nom]').val($('input:hidden[name=poste_nom]').val());

            $('.formation').empty();
            $('.formation').prepend(data.formation)
            $('input[name=user_credit_cpf]').val(data.resDisplayForm.user_credit_cpf).val());
        }
    });
  });
});
```

**My HTML file :**

```
$displaySalarie = $bdd->query('SELECT user_id, user_prenom, user_nom FROM USER ORDER BY user_nom ASC');
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="formEtape1" id="formEtape1" method="post">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Etape-1">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Information Salarié</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nomSalarie" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nom</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <select class="form-control" name="nomSalarie" id="idSalarie">
                      <option disabled selected>Choisir un salarié</option>
                      <?php while($ligne = $displaySalarie->fetch()){?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $ligne['user_id'];?>"><?php echo $ligne['user_nom'].' '.$ligne['user_prenom'];?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="salarie"></div>        
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Informations Entretien</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
           <div class="formation"></div>
            </div>
       </form>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what (in json format) the server sends after an Ajax call?

Comment: Please do a `console.log(data)` inside the success callback of AJAX and let us know of the output